# Git functions requiring SSH broken on Cygwin

Tags: ssh, windows, git, cygwin

On Cygwin, running `git clone git@...`, `git pull` or `git push`, where the remote is an SSH repository address, fails. Below is output of running `git clone`:

```
Cloning into 'iko-app-rocket'...
fatal: cannot run C:\Users\sakynimoD\scoop\apps\openssh\current\bin\ssh.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

As you can see from the path, I had used [scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop), the Windows package manager. I used it to install Gradle, and it installed some other things as dependencies, including ssh. I've since deinstalled scoop, in the recommended way, along with all the packages it installed, but the error persists.

A workaround is declaring that git should use the `ssh` executable for SSH, which sounds rendundant, but apparently isn't: `env GIT_SSH=ssh git pull` works.

Comment: @derobert, `GIT_SSH` was set in Windows' environment variable settings. Unsetting fixed the problem. Please submit as answer, so I may accept it.

Comment: Answer added. Please feel free to edit my answer to add in where the Windows environment variable settings are — they used to be at right-click My Computer, but no idea where they are on modern Windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you discovered that explicitly setting `GIT_SSH=ssh` works, the next thing to investigate is if it was already set, possibly by scoop. You can check by running `echo "$GIT_SSH"` or alternatively by running `env` to display the entire environment.

If it is set, that could either be coming from Windows' environment variable settings or from a `.bashrc` or similar.